# php form uploading multiple image for specific name

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

i have created a php form in user has to enter username and upload multiple image, latter one is working fine but it is not replicating the username for every image
in table i have two columns `image`, `name` but it is taking value for only first column other are left blank

php code given below

```
<?php 
$size=count($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
for($i=0; $i < $size;$i++)
{
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$i]);
    $imagefile=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["photo"]["name"][$i]);
    if ((($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["photo"]["size"][$i] < 10485760))//9 mb
      {
      if ($_FILES["photo"]["error"][$i] > 0)
        {
        $Error=$Error.' '.$_FILES["photo"]["error"];
        }
      else
        {
        $path="image/".$_FILES["photo"]["name"][$i];    
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$i],$path);
         $sql="INSERT INTO restimage (name, rest_image) "."VALUES('$name','$imagefile')";
     $retval = mysql_query($sql);

        }
      }
    else
      {
      $Error=$Error.' '.$_FILES["photo"]["name"][$i] .' is corrupt file or not choosen ';
      }
}
if($Error =="")
{
echo "images uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
echo $Error;
}
?>
```

HTML part

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
<input type="file" name="photo[]" >
```

**there is only one field to enter name and four field to upload four images**

Comment: your form should have 'enctype= multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this;

```
<?php 
$size=count($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
for($i=0; $i < $size;$i++)
{
.....

}
```

You need to get username once out of for loop

**Edit:** Use only one username text box on your html like;

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
```

Comment: Have you put log in for loop inor der to see values for insert statement?

Comment: You can do that `error_log("Name : $name, image: $imagefile", 3, "path/to/log/log_file.txt");`.

Comment: do i need to change this <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">

Comment: i did that but it is showing error for this $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

Answer (score 0):

only two columns you have specified,then how could it stores all the columns..

```
$sql="INSERT INTO restimage (name, rest_image) "."VALUES('$name','$imagefile')";
```

Try uploading function out of the for loop by taking the uploaded image file names into an extra array in the for loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Place this line of code

```
  $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$i]);
```

out of the loop

and change it to

```
   $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

It will look something like this

```
 <?php 
 $size=count($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
 $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
 for($i=0; $i < $size;$i++)
 {
 ....
```

Comment: Your answer is exact same with mine, it would be better checking answers before post

Comment: actually there is a small but significant difference. in your answer you are using `$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$i]);` which is plain wrong because `$_POST['name']` is not an array. its a string. so doing this `$_POST['name'][$i]` has 2 issues. first of all `$i` is not set before calling this. second of all it, if `$i` was set to say `0` then you would have got the first character of the string, which is wrong again. so i'm afraid our answers aren't exactly the same

Comment: Yes, I have forgot to remove that while copying, thanks

Comment: @anurupur but it is showing error is it due to <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name"> ..